# Scheduled Facebook post throws unexpected error

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm trying to post a link to my site to my Facebook fan page using Graph API/Facebook PHP SDK. When I don't specify a scheduled time and don't set 'published' to 0 it works fine and my post instantly appears on the fan page.

However, I want the post to appear delayed by 15 minutes. This throws an exception:

```
An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later.
```

Can anybody help me out here?

This is my code:

```
$config = array();
$config['appId'] = '###';
$config['secret'] = '###';

$fb = new Facebook($config);

$params = array(
    'access_token' => "###",
    'message' => 'My message',
    'link' => 'http://www.example.com/',
    'picture' => 'http://link.to/my/picture.jpg',
    'name' => 'My message',
    'caption' => 'example.com',
    'description' => 'My description goes here.',
    'published' => 0,
    'scheduled_facebook_time' => time() + 900  // 15 mins
);

try {
    $fb->api('/mypageid/feed', 'POST', $params);
}
catch(Exception $ex) {
    // ...
}
```

Strange thing: When I remove the 'picture' part, the post is scheduled, but just the message in plain text without the link (and the picture obviously).

Comment: It sounds like you've found a bug with the Graph API.  You may want to notify Facebook that you are not able to schedule a post that includes an image for a later time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it. Had nothing to do with the Facebook API or the picture after all. Problem was that in my real code the link (here `http://www.example.com/`) pointed to localhost. Facebook doesn't seem to like that, which is quite understandable.

Odd thing though: When I want to publish directly, using a localhost link doesn't give me any trouble.